# javascript flash message

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone app that renders announcements into the dom, however, I would like the announcements to disappear after a few seconds. I'm guessing that, after displaying the announcement, I should just call a function that removes it, but is there a way to delay its execution, or to create a callback after I display the template.  Sorry if this is an easy question.

```
   $(this.el).html(this.template({ announcement: announcement}));

     this.removeAnnouncement(); 
  },

  removeAnnounce: function(){
    this.$el.remove();
  },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use setTimeout:

```
window.setTimeout(_.bind(this.removeAnnounce, this), 2000);
```

This will call `this.removeAnnounce` after `2000` milliseconds (or 2 seconds). Just note, don't add the `()` after the `this.removeAnnounce` as you are actually passing a function reference. The timeout will invoke the function after the time has elapsed.

EDIT: The `_.bind` portion is making sure the the `this` in scope is correctly assigned when the timeout calls the function. Thanks @PaulHoenecke

Comment: Should be `window.setTimeout(_.bind(this.removeAnnounce, this), 2000);` I think, since `this` in `removeAnnounce` would be `window` without the binding.

Comment: @PaulHoenecke Agreed, I was just looking up if there was a clean way to bind in backbone.js. You saved me most of the effort. :)

Comment: thanks, why do I need the window prefix? (the remove Announcement function's in the same view.) Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The `window` object is what contains the `setTimeout` function. In most browsers you can omit it, but it tends to be safer to keep it in there for scoping reasons. Just make sure that the function you reference matches the function you've defined. (Your question has `removeAnnouncement` and `removeAnnounce`)